# How do I change the color of CoffeeScript TODO comments in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, coffeescript

I'm using the **Darcula** color scheme which I think is very relevant.  I wrote a todo comment in coffeescript and it looks just like the color of a String which I don't like.  I want it to be a different color that stands out but I can't figure out how to change it.  Here's a screenshot showing what I'm talking about:

[image: Bad todo color]

How do I make the "todo" stand out like it normally does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  It's under

> Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> General -> TODO defaults

My mistake was looking for it under "CoffeeScript" instead of General